# WFS request returns FeatureCollection with no feature - OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Created the WFS feature request as following:

```
this.map.getViewport().addEventListener("click", (evt) => { 

  //Point transformation to EPSG:25830
  var proyeccion = getProjection('EPSG:25830');
  var p = new Point(this.map.getEventCoordinate(evt)).transform(this.map.getView().getProjection(),proyeccion);

  //WFS Feature Request
  var featureRequest = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
    srsName: 'EPSG:25830',
    featurePrefix: 'CP',
    featureTypes: ['CadastralParcel'],
    outputFormat: 'application/json',
    filter: containsFilter('MultiPolygon',p,'EPSG:25830')
  });

  fetch('https://inspire.navarra.es/services/CP/wfs', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest)
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((json) => {
    var features = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
    this.vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
  });
});
```

This makes the `getFeature` request correctly using `POST`, with the following request payload:

```
<GetFeature xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" outputFormat="application/json" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <Query typeName="CP:CadastralParcel" srsName="EPSG:25830">
        <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <Contains>
                <PropertyName>MultiPolygon</PropertyName>
                <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:25830">
                    <pos srsDimension="2">586784.8369967575 4722127.891344394</pos>
                </Point>
            </Contains>
        </Filter>
    </Query>
</GetFeature>
```

But the request above returns an empty `FeatureCollection` when clicking a point where there is a feature. The type of Features that I was supposed to get were Polygon.

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":"unknown","features":[],"crs":null}
```

Guess it could be because of the projections, but don't know where the mistake is.

[image: Request details]

**EDIT**

I'm using projection EPSG:25830. Defined like this:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:25830","+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
register(proj4);
```

Added to the map's view and layers as following:

```
const proyeccion = getProjection('EPSG:25830');

view: new View({
    projection: proyeccion,
    center: fromLonLat([-1.629950,42.63],proyeccion),
    zoom: 9
})

//WMS
source: new TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/idena',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'catastro'},
    projection: proyeccion
})
```

Comment: If spatial reference issues are the likely cause, then it's probably pretty important to specify what the spatial references in use are. Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: Projection is not a parameter of the Point geometry constructor.  If your view projection is different to the data projection replace `var p = new Point(this.map.getEventCoordinate(evt),proyeccion);` with `var p = new Point(this.map.getEventCoordinate(evt)).transform(map.getView().getProjection(),proyeccion);` otherwise simply remove `proyeccion`.  Also there is unlikely to be a point feature at the exact coordinate of the click event as that can only be calculated to the accuracy of one pixel, you should filter for features within a one pixel (at least) tolerance of that.

Comment: Hi @Mike thanks for the answer. The wanted features are Polygons, the Point is the click event coordinates. I'm trying to get the polygon feature that contains it.

Comment: `<PropertyName>Point</PropertyName>` refers to the name of the geometry field of your featuretype `CP:CadastralParcel`. I guess that it is not correct.

Comment: @user30184 Even with the correct geometry (MultiPolygon), the Feature Collection is still empty :(

Comment: Check the schema with DescribeFeatureType. Example: https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typename=states. In this case the name of the geometry is `the_geom`. For you it seems to be `CP:geometry`.

Comment: This is the [used schema](https://inspire.navarra.es/services/CP/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typename=CP:CadastralParcel). Can't find anything interesting there

Comment: Right, you should continue and check the CadastralParcels.xsd. An easier way is to read one feature https://inspire.navarra.es/services/CP/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=CP:CadastralParcel&maxFeatures=1.

Comment: Finally! You were right!!! @user30184 the problem was on `filter: containsFilter('geometry',p,'EPSG:25830')`, I set `Point` instead of `geometry`. You made my day, please answer the question for marking as solution. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used wrong PropertyName in your filter

```
<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <Contains>
        <PropertyName>MultiPolygon</PropertyName>
        <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:25830">
            <pos srsDimension="2">586784.8369967575 4722127.891344394</pos>
        </Point>
    </Contains>
</Filter>
```

The PropertyName must be the name of the geometry as it is announced in the schema of the PropertyType. In WFS the schema can be read with the DescribeFeatureType request. For example the schema of a GeoServer demo layer https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typename=states

shows that the name of the geometry is "the_geom"

```
<xsd:element name="the_geom" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

In your case the request is https://inspire.navarra.es/services/CP/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typename=CP:CadastralParcel

The response does not show the schema directly but it has a reference to the INSPIRE schema document http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0/CadastralParcels.xsd that you can try to interpret. Another option is to read one feature with GetFeature request and check the name of the geometry from the response https://inspire.navarra.es/services/CP/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=CP:CadastralParcel&maxFeatures=1

```
<gml:featureMember>
<CP:CadastralParcel gml:id="ES.RRTN.CP.1010001">
<CP:areaValue uom="m2">101.2779</CP:areaValue>
<CP:beginLifespanVersion nilReason="other:unpopulated" xsi:nil="true"/>
<CP:geometry>MULTIPOLYGON (((42.64858704034896 -2.141289282470453, ...
```

The full name of the geometry is CP:geometry but your experience seems to suggest that the namespace part must be dropped and filter that works looks like

```
<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <Contains>
        <PropertyName>geometry</PropertyName>
        <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:25830">
            <pos srsDimension="2">586784.8369967575 4722127.891344394</pos>
        </Point>
    </Contains>
</Filter>
```